# pywin32 - restrict, filtering by a list of potential senders

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I need to iterate through every email within my project. I have more than 20000 mails. Therefore i read I need to use the restrict function. I found examples how to restrict to one specific domain

```
messages = messages.Restrict("@SQL=(urn:schemas:httpmail:SenderEmailAddress LIKE '%@domain.com')")
```

What do I need to use if have more than 100 domains or multiple (more than 100) Senders I want to use? Would it be a huge restrict function with logical OR connectors with all of the domains or can I input somehow a list into the restrict statement?

EDIT:

and i realized if i run a restrict function with this code, it just shows me with the len(messages) function that there are 0 emails while i can see a bunch of emails in outlook with used domain in the filter. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? Would most of your emails match one of those 100 domains?

Comment: I want to build a guided lda analaysis about the emails within a company. for that im only allowed to analyse the customer communication and not the communication from employee to employee. so if a customer is the sender in the mail im allowed to store the body in my database. a good chunk of the mails would be in this 100 domains, yes. but it could range between 20-80%. there are more than 100000 mails at my company (last two years of mails)

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would need to use the logical `OR` operator in the search string. Read more about that in the [Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison) article. Also you may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

But I would recommend handling each domain separately, so you will get Outlook running without freezes and will be able to process items in a logical bunch, especially when you have a hundred of domain names to search for.

Comment: Im trying to connect the query with an or but it just won't work. python just tells me EOL. It seems that there is a weird syntax and my code and the quotation and bracjet character messes up everything. is there any chance you could maybe show me how it would look if you would connect to domain filters with an or filter? i tried diferrent versions but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out internal senders and only process the senders outside your organization, check the `SenderEmailType` property - it will be `"EX"` for the internal senders (assuming you are using Exchange Server) and `"SMTP"` for the external senders.